# HTTPPOST method not being called while using html.beginform

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, html.beginform

I hope somebody can help me with this simple issue I'm having, but can't figure it out.

I was using Ajax calls in javascript to submit my forms which was no problem.

I'm trying now to use the html.beginform helper, but it is not hitting the post method inside the same controller that I was using for the Ajax call.

What do I need to do in order for the post method to be hit?

Here is my Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Category category)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    await db.AddCategoryAsync(category);


                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }

            return View(category);
        }
```

Here is my html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="body-content">
        <h4>Category</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Description" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="btnCategoryCreate" class="btn btn-primary col-offset-2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here is the url in my browser when I click on the submit button. It is inside my *Home* Controller executing a *Create* method, but during debugging, the Controller method never gets hit.

Someone **PLEASE** help and let me know what simple mistake I'm overlooking...

```
http://localhost:1681/Home/Create?Description=Medical
```

### EDIT

Value of Form tag
OK.. the issue is..
On the form action tag which reads:
"Saw a 'form' start tag, but there was already an active 'form' element. Nested forms are not allowed. Ignoring this tag ().

That's why it's not posting.

I removed the form tag in the _Layout.cshtml file, and now it's posting because there is only one form tag now for this specific page whereas when I was using all my calls via Ajax, I had the form tag in my _Layout.cshtml file.

However, my button is off to the right of the textbox instead of being underneath it when I had the following for the Ajax calls with one form:

```
<form id="form1" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

I tried placing the following on the @html.BeginForm tag, but the button is still to the right.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="form-horizontal", role="form"}}))
```

**How can I get my button underneath the input box now?**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="form-horizontal", role="form"}}))
{
    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="body-content">
        <h4>Category</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-offset-1 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Description" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="btnCategoryCreate" class="btn btn-primary col-offset-2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: What is the value of the form tags `action` attribute?

Comment: Please see my Edit and would appreciate how to get the proper button alignment when using bootstrap with an html.beginform.

Comment: I used the following to align the form correctly: @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post,  new { @class="form-horizontal"}))

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to call the methode Async or not?

Try to add more information to the HTML form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

If you want to use Ajax and async use:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm())
```